# Django manage.py sqlclear omit some tables

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wrote python script for dropping tables in all Django apps. (using settings.INSTALLED_APP)

https://gist.github.com/1520683

My django project creates **41** tables after running `manage.py syncdb`, but my script says only **40** tables will be dropped. So, I examined the result of `sqlall` and result of `sqlclear`. And I revealed `sqlclear` omits one table that stores `ManyToManyField` relationship.

I knew that `drop database` is much simpler than the above script. But I confused why django admin or manage script omit some tables while running sql commands.

---

Below model creates `common_userbook_purchasedBooks` table while running `syncdb`, but not in `sqlclear` command.

```
class UserBook(models.Model):                       
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    purchasedBooks = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

---

Added) So, I'm using an alternative approach for this.
https://gist.github.com/1520810

Comment: What's the name of the omitted table?

Comment: @SimonKagwi I attached my model. Thankss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lqez, I gues this issue related to you local environment, because for Django 1.3.1, Python 2.7.2

for models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class UserBook(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    purchasedBooks = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

when I run `(.env)testme$ ./manage.py sqlclear testapp` output looks like

#### sqlite3

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "testapp_userbook";
DROP TABLE "testapp_userbook_purchasedBooks";
DROP TABLE "testapp_book";
COMMIT;
```

#### postgresql_psycopg2

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE "testapp_userbook_purchasedBooks" DROP CONSTRAINT "userbook_id_refs_id_8bda4b0";
DROP TABLE "testapp_userbook";
DROP TABLE "testapp_userbook_purchasedBooks";
DROP TABLE "testapp_book";
COMMIT;
```

#### mysql

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE `testapp_userbook_purchasedBooks` DROP FOREIGN KEY `userbook_id_refs_id_8bda4b0`;
DROP TABLE `testapp_userbook`;
DROP TABLE `testapp_userbook_purchasedBooks`;
DROP TABLE `testapp_book`;
COMMIT;
```

Also your script can be a little bit improved using `introspection`:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.introspection.get_table_list(cursor)

[u'auth_group', u'auth_group_permissions', u'auth_message', u'auth_permission', u'auth_user', u'auth_user_groups', u'auth_user_user_permissions', u'django_content_type', u'django_session', u'django_site', u'testapp_book', u'testapp_userbook', u'testapp_userbook_purchasedBooks']
```

Comment: Thank you for testing! I got the above bad result on Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) + Django 1.3.1.

Comment: This symptom is not occurred again via clean new django project (same environment). So it looks like not depends on the environment. Anyway, thank you for your posting.

Comment: During testing I found that syncdb use the models.py to generate sql, vice versa sqlclear checks database. So maybe this table corrupted?